# How to resolve Apple - o link error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4, xcode6, xcode5

I am having one apple - o link error in my project, I have searched in Google but it's not helping me, below is my error

```
   ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

what is this error and how to fix it, please any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try avoid arm64 from valid architecture.
2.Try Set Build for Active Architecture to "NO"
3.Also check framework search path

@ build settings.

[image: screen shot - valid architecture]
[image: screen shot - Build for active architecture]
[image: screen shot - Framework search path]

Comment: what architecture i have to give?

Comment: after removing that, i get this error : error: failed to remove /Users/gowthamrajk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Galatta-epbjetmogxudrabbulncayoqodaf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Galatta.app/UnitTests-Info.plist: “UnitTests-Info.plist” couldn’t be removed.

Comment: check "Build For Active Architecture" and "Framework search path"

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by following this steps:

Select the Pods project

Click on build settings

Change Build Active Architecture Only to 'No'